# WPF main window does not return

Tags: c#, wpf

The problem is that my program does not return after `return;` statement. Maybe I am just tired and cannot find obvious mistake but... it continues its work after Return and opens the window. What the heck?

And yes, my program enters IF statement.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        bool checkingResult = FileChecker.CheckFiles();
        if (!checkingResult)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Required files are missing.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            return;
        }

        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program get into the if statement?

Comment: So you want to close the application if `checkingResult` is `false`? If so then place a `this.Close();` before the `return`.

Comment: Yes. Program enters if-statement and after MainWindow() method it opens the window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MainWindow()` is just a constructor. The application doesn't terminate when this constructor returns. Use `Application.Current.Shutdown()` to properly close a WPF app.